# Error using Texture2D.getPixle()

Tags: texture2d

The error is

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object mapS.Start () (at Assets/mapS.cs:25)

The part with the error in the code

```
Texture2D img = Resources.Load(@"\images\1") as Texture2D
Color try1 = img.GetPixel(0,0);
print(try1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The texture's read/write option was disabled